# How to Use Global List in different function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I have a function: instanceDetails() in which I am trying to use global variables, global lists are declared in just after class definition.

```
class InstanceDescribe:
    #both variables are global
    all_instances_health = [0]          #stores some ids such as ip-address
    all_instances_health_index = [0]    #against the IP address stores health of server

    #some code goes here
    
    def instanceDetails():
    
       #some code goes here to find value of instance_role, instanceId and much more which is used as  argument
       if instance_role=='dispatcherpub' or instance_role=='dispatcheraut':
    
        if instanceId in **all_instances_health**:   #checking IP address is in global variable list
            print("Yes instance in list, so not calling target gp health function")
            position = **all_instances_health.index(instanceId)**
            instanceDetailsresult_dict["Health Status"] = **all_instances_health_index[position]**
        else:                                         #if IP address is not there then calling another function and this function returns values
            print("No instance is not in  list, so calling target gp health function")
            return_list = target_object.target_gp_health(instanceId,autoscaling_group_name,cross_account_cred_list)
            instanceDetailsresult_dict["Health Status"] = return_list[0]

            **all_instances_health** = return_list[1]
            **all_instances_health_index** = return_list[2]
```

Now, could you please tell me, where I have to use global keyword so that my function starts working.
I have tried so many things but getting error such as:
***name 'all_instances_health' is used prior to global declaration***
and after some putting global keyword with list name under if and else block, am getting this error also:
***name 'all_instances_health' is not defined***

**NOTE: other functionalities are working properly**

Answer (score 0):

Use it at the start of the functions. I tried that and it worked.

```
def instanceDetails():
    global var1
    global var2
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @tdserapio, Yes I have added both globals variables just after def instanceDetails() but after this I am getting: name 'all_instances_health' is not defined, this issue I am getting at line: if instanceId in **all_instances_health**

Comment: And variable name is exactly same as global ones

Comment: I dont really get what you mean. You can just check with an if statement if it is there